# Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.ts(8010) - React tsx file

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using `core-ui` project and I am trying implement `Typescript` on my component files.
I'm getting an error from `VSCODE` which does't allow me to use it in files with `tsx` extention.

```js
const TheLayout: React.FunctionComponent = () => {}
```

Getting the following error:

```
Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.ts(8010)
```

My `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "build",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "files.associations": {
    "*.tsx": "typescriptreact",
    "*.ts": "typescriptreact"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: have you figured something, cuz nothing on earth could fix it for me !

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the problem comes when using VSCode type-checkers extensions. In my personal case, I had Flow Type-Checker installed and therefore the linting error jumped up. I turned it off and the error disappeared

Hope it may be useful for you!